# File locked after removing the layer , in Python code for a plugin for QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins

I try to remove the layer, to re-generate it with the same name, but when the plug is started the layer is loaded, removeMapLayer does not unlock the file, and it is locked.

I have seen several messages from people who have had the same problem but no solution is currently serving me.

```
QgsProject.instance().removeMapLayer(layer_.id())
os.remove(url_layer)
```

Comment: Can you share your code on the relevant part so that we can reproduce your problem. 
Also share error messages.